# How to concatenate multi multipage tiff files?

Tags: tiff

I am trying to concatenate multiple multi-page tiff files. Not merge them into one single tiff but joining all the files so that each starts with x'49 49 2A 00 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as any other file:

- `copy/b file1+file2+file3 outputfile` on Windows,
- `cat file1 file2 file3 > outputfile` on all Unixes (including Linux, OS X and Cygwin).

Comment: this did the trick. At least now I understand what the expected result is. How now do I incorporate this into a C# program to be able to get the offset values of each file that is concatenated to the final file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Zorna: You do it by using an actual *archive* format that is *designed* to contain multiple files (like Zip or Tar), instead of blindly concatenating three files and hoping to guess the offsets later. There is *no guarantee* that a `\x49\x49\x2a\x00` won't occur in the *middle* of a TIFF file.

Comment: I've been given this as a requirement, using zip is not an option. The files are all of the type \x49\x49\x2a\x00 and need to be joined in order to be transmitted and then split and uploaded into a Content Manager system in another part of the world from where I am. Hence I must persist in trying to find the solution to this this.

Comment: So basically after I've created this file I need to read the length in bytes which will provide the offset value of the next file in the concatenated file.